# lubuntu notify-send not starting with session

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, autostart

I'll try to send me a text reminder in lubuntu 20.04. I have 2 in my autostart ($HOME/.config/autostart) one works the second not.

the working executes a bash-skript that is placed in /usr/local/bin/
for the second I create a desktop file under $HOME/.config/autostart/

```
cat .config/autostart/firefox-hold.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/notify-send "firefox auf hold gesetzt"
Name=firefox-hold
Type=Application
OnlyShowIn=LXQt;
Version=1.0
```

I activate it in

```
lxqt-config-session
```

looking in .xsession-errors

```
+ /usr/bin/notify-send -i /usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/status/dialog-warning.png Warnung 'home voll' # the working one
```

from the second

```
notify-send \"firefox auf hold gesetzt\" #looks strange
```

In Terminal the command `notify-send "firefox auf hold gesetzt"` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not explain why it is now working after changing
my file to

```
cat .config/autostart/firefox-hold.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=/usr/bin/notify-send "firefox auf hold gesetzt"
Name=firefox-hold
Type=Application
Version=1.0
#OnlyShowIn=LXQt 
X-LXQt-Need-Tray=true
```

Now I got my reminder

```
[2022-01-18-13-08-34-593]
Actions=@Invalid()
Application=notify-send
Body=
Hints=@Variant(\0\0\0\b\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\xe\0u\0r\0g\0\x65\0n\0\x63\0y\0\0\0\x86\x1)
Icon=
Summary=firefox auf hold gesetzt
TimeOut=5000
```

As bubble and in lxqt-notificationd